# angular 5 - email validator

Tags: validation, angular5

I use this statement in order to validate the email:

```
email: ['', [Validators.email, Validators.minLength(2)]]
```

It is not necessary in my application to enter an email.
Is it possible to specify something like **Validators.notRequired**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be `Validators.email` didn't allow optional input. It seems to be fixed in angular [6.0.0-beta4](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/20869).

You can try workaround discussed [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16183).

> ```
> function emailOrEmpty(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
>     return control.value === '' ? null : Validators.email(control); 
>  }
> ```

And your field:

```
email: ['', [this.emailOrEmpty, Validators.minLength(2)]]
```